# Show invalidated votes to moderators

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, serial-voting

As a less-intrusive alternative to [Raise an automatic flag when a serial vote reversal occurs more than once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237961/139866), moderators should be able to monitor when votes have been invalidated. This can already be done on a per-user basis, but that's only useful if you're already suspicious of a specific user.

Therefore invalidated votes ought to appear on the `admin/show-suspicious-votes` page.

Comment: Something like "recently invalidated", right? Good idea.

Comment: Something like, "in the most recent week/month/quarter/year", like similar UIs. The record of invalidated votes must exist in the database (it's displayed on a per-user basis), it's just a matter of making it visible. I think it ought to be useful for detecting sock-puppets ... there are tools to prove sock-puppetry if you're suspicious, IMO this tool would be helpful (sometimes necessary) to arouse suspicion in the first place. The downside of sock-puppets isn't only vote fraud, they can decrease the quality of the content on the site (by posting useless stuff just so that it can be upvoted).